# TFS2010 Query - Find Orphan Tasks?

Tags: workitem

I'm using the MSF Agile 5.0 project template.

I'm looking to modify the Product Backlog query to include tasks that have no parents.  The query currently only shows User Stories.

I don't see a field to query against such as parent item id or similar.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why are you looking to include tasks? The product backlog is to prioritize the User stories. If you want to plan on tasks, then use the Iteration backlog.

To achieve this result you can use the "Work items and direct links" type of query. Then in the 'top grid' specify the work item type = "task" and in the 'bottom grid' specify the work item type = 'user story. Then change the linking filter to "only return items that do not have the specified links"

Comment: Ok, ignore the fact I said Product Backlog.  I want a report that will show me any Tasks without User Stories that have not been assigned to an Iteration, I don't care what it's called.

Comment: You can use the "Work items and direct links" type of query. Then in the 'top grid' specify the work item type = "task" and in the 'bottom grid' specify the work item type = 'user story. Then change the linking filter to "only return items that do not have the specified links"

Comment: Aha, thanks.  In order to get the query I actually want I set the query type to Work Items and Direct Links, set the top grid Work Item Type to Any, set the bottom grid Work Item Type to Any and set the linking filters to return selected link types of Parent and not to return any items with the specified links.  This gives me all items with no parent  :)  I'll mark you answer as accepted for the comment above.